# bash: cannot execute binary file while trying mesh_view in trimesh2

Tags: bash, graphics, debian, mesh

I am trying to run **trimesh2** on my 64-bit **debian**,

but whenever I try to run **mesh_view** or any other `mesh` command, it says

> cannot execute binary file

What should I do to run the `mesh`? The Makefile looks like this:

```
all win32 linux32 linux64 darwin32 darwin64 clean:
$(MAKE) -C libsrc $@
$(MAKE) -C gluit $@
$(MAKE) -C utilsrc $@

debug:
$(MAKE) -C libsrc DEBUG=y
$(MAKE) -C gluit DEBUG=y
$(MAKE) -C utilsrc DEBUG=y

FINDCMD = find trimesh2 -name 'OBJ*' -prune -o -name CVS -prune -o -type f -print

tar:
cd .. && tar zcvf trimesh2.tar.gz `$(FINDCMD) | sort`

zip:
cd .. && $(FINDCMD) | sort | zip -9 trimesh2 -@

.PHONY : all clean debug default tar win32 zip
```

Comment: Did you run `make all` or `make linuxNN` (32 or 64, as appropriate to your system). If the makefile has a `make clean` I would run that first, and then `make linuxNN`. The error message you're getting indicates mismatch of binary types either in the main executable or in the "type" of .so files that are being found while traversing LD_LIBRARY_PATH. (I think! ;-) ) . Good luck.

Comment: There are 171 questions here on S.O. if you'll search for `"cannot execute binary file"`. You should find more detailed instructions in some of those for resolving your problem. Good luck.